# Compilation error for interactivity and interaction

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to execute the following `xaml` code which has reference to interactivity and interactions as shown and I keep getting errors.

The `xaml` code is attached below with the comments where errors are appearing.

```
<Grid 
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <Popup x:Name="popup" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=imageList}">
        <Image Source="{Binding PlacementTarget.SelectedItem , ElementName=popup}"/>
    </Popup>
    <ListView x:Name="imageList" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>  //ERROR
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged"> //ERROR
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="IsOpen" 
                    TargetName="{Binding ElementName=popup}" Value="True"/> //ERROR
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I want to display selected image in a new window. But the following errors occur.

Comment: You missed the errors off but I guess your issue is because you haven't referenced the dll in your project. Which I think is now a nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add references (Project->Add Reference->Assemblies in Visual Studio) to `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` and `Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions.dll`.

They are part of the Blend SDK which can be downloaded from [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801) or by installing [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Expression.Blend.Sdk/) (Tools->Nuget Package Manager->Package Manager Console) into your project.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same errors while working with an [Elmish.WPF project's C# Sample project 'NewWindow'.](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/tree/master/src/Samples/NewWindow)  The solution was found in this StackOverflow Q&A: [Interaction triggers inside DataTemplate not working with XamlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073375/interaction-triggers-inside-datatemplate-not-working-with-xamlreader).

The answer for me was to add :

```
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

... to the XAML page's defintions at top.  And add the Nuget package `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` (I'm working with a WPF project, you might just want `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors`).