Using a attached property in generated templates causes a XamlParseException
I am having trouble with using attached properties in a dynamic template.
I am writing an custom control. That control is supposed to display items from some collection and i want to enable the users of that control to provide an DisplayMemberPath, which i can achive by generating the ItemTemplate with an XamlReader like this:
private DataTemplate CreateItemTemplate()
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
$@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:MyControl"">
        <TextBlock Text=""{{Binding {DisplayMemberPath}}}""/>
</DataTemplate>");
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
}

Now i want some attached Properties to add additional behavior to the template. Like this simple attached string property:
internal class Foobar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BazProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Baz",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Foobar),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnTextChanged));

    public static string GetBaz(FrameworkElement frameworkElement) => (string)frameworkElement.GetValue(BazProperty);
    public static void SetBaz(FrameworkElement frameworkElement, string value) => frameworkElement.SetValue(BazProperty, value);

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}

I can use this attached property directly inside the view xaml just fine. But if i try to use this property inside the template i get an XamlParseException Cannot set unknown member "{clr-namespace:MyControl}Foobar.Baz" at runtime:
private DataTemplate CreateItemTemplate()
{
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(
$@"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" xmlns:local=""clr-namespace:MyControl"">
        <TextBlock Text=""{{Binding {DisplayMemberPath}}}"" local:Foobar.Baz=""Baz""/>
</DataTemplate>");
    XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
    return XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
}

What am i missing?
Edit: In addition to Sinus32's answer i had to change the access modifer for the class that defines the attached property from internal to public.

XamlReader don't know which assembly contains the MyControl namespace.
Change xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControl"
into xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyControl;assembly=put_your_assembly_name_here".
Besides of that, why you're doing this that way? This solution is really overcomplicated and prone to Xaml injection. Just allow the users of the control to pass item template, don't create one at runtime.

This does not seem to solve the problem. I am getting the same error with the assembly name added to the xml namespace.
Why i am doing this that way?
I want to provide a default template that makes use of a DisplayMemberPath Property. As far as i know it is not possible to do this in plain xaml.

That's stange. Similar question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70073375/interaction-triggers-inside-datatemplate-not-working-with-xamlreader
The only thing that have to be done is to load the assembly and reference it properly. Nothing else should be required. In your case the assembly should be already loaded.

The missing assembly definition was part of the problem. In addition to that i had to change the access modifier of the class that defined the attached property.
